# Google Earth Engine - Scripts, Docs, Assets tabs Missing

Tags: google-earth-engine

My Scripts, Assets and Docs tabs are simply missing from my code editor interface (left panel) and I cannot access any of my assets and scripts. The problem has been persisting for the past several weeks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the Code Editor user interface, there are four panes which can all be resized or entirely hidden with split-bars (for example, to maximize the space available for script text on a small screen). In your case, the Scripts/Docs/Assets pane has been hidden this way, and to retrieve it you can drag this split-bar to the right:

[image: Picture of split bar marked by arrows]